# HTML PHP form post showing up blank?

Tags: php, html, post

I have two files, testpage.html and testpage.php in the same folder.

This is testpage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<form action="testpage.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is testpage.php

```
<html> 
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br> 
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?><br> 

</body>
</html>
```

The form seems to work okay but when I hit submit nothing shows up on the next page. no matter what I enter int he form, it always reads "Welcome" "Your email address is:" with nothing entered after that like its supposed to.

Do I have something configured incorrectly? Am I using the wrong browser (firefox)?

Thanks!

Comment: When you view the page source, what specifically do you see?

Comment: *"Am I using the wrong browser (firefox)?"* - Smells like `file:///C:/file.xxx` instead of a host.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page

Comment: Does it work if you add this attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your <form> at testpage.php?

Comment: @Fred-ii- if that were the case, he would see PHP code. I think it might have something to do with invalid HTML? No idea, but it's always a good idea to AUTO-CLOSE TAGS `<input .... />`

Comment: @AlexanderMP I'm thinking OP isn't telling us the full story and accessing as `file:///C:/file.xxx` instead of `http://host/file.xxx`. Least, that's my take on it, or their server's not properly configured. This *"Do I have something configured incorrectly? Am I using the wrong browser (firefox)?"* is a sign and a very unclear one at that.

Comment: Do you have Xampp activated or any virtual server to test your PHP? Or did you tested it online? people are right, you're probably accessing it directly in your folder but it won't work this way

Comment: I am accessing it via file:///C:/... should I be accessing it some other way instead?

Comment: Yes, you should be accessing it via a web server that is running PHP.

Comment: I don't think I have Xampp or any virtual server set up... I'll look into that, any tips on where to start?

Comment: seems to be working just fine http://codepad.viper-7.com/wkFKTK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"I am accessing it via file:///C:/... should I be accessing it some other way instead?"*

- Just as I thought.

There you go. A web browser will not parse PHP directives that way.

It must be accessed as `http://localhost/yourfile.xxx`

Plus, a webserver and PHP need to be installed in order to parse PHP directives.

> *"I don't think I have Xampp or any virtual server set up... I'll look into that, any tips on where to start?"*

You need to install one. Here are a few links to get you started and depending on the platform you are using.

- https://www.apachefriends.org/
- http://www.wampserver.com/
- https://www.mamp.info
- http://www.easyphp.org/

Pick your flavour.